# Access property of a returned object without a temporary variable

Tags: matlab, oop, object, properties

How does one access the properties of a returned object without a temporary object?

Or, to make myself clear, how do I turn this code into one line ?

```
temp = info(AFR)
Fs = temp.SampleRate
```

I tried

```
Fs = info(AFR).SampleRate
```

and

```
Fs = (info(AFR)).SampleRate
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `SampleRate` is a *method*, then you can use the `method(obj)` syntax instead which doesn't require a temporary variable.

```
SampleRate(info(AFR));
```

If `SampleRate` is just a *property*, then you could possibly use this method if `AFR` is an object itself

```
AFR.info().SampleRate
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use a temporary variable

That being said, there's really no benefit to not using a temporary variable.

Comment: It's just that it can get messy when I have to use a temporary variable every other line. I like my code to be clear :) You solution works perfectly, thank you

Comment: @user3548298 Check out the second option that I just added.